# Can't install or upgrade Python 3.10.8 in WSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sudo

I need to specifically install Python 3.10.8 for school, but I can't seem to get a version higher than 3.10.6

`sudo apt-get install python3.10` just result in telling me that python3.10 is already the newest version (3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1.1)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3.10 is already the newest version (3.10.6-1~22.04.2ubuntu1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I already did `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and this is what I got:

```
Failed to start apt-news.service: Unit apt-news.service not found.
Failed to start esm-cache.service: Unit esm-cache.service not found.
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease \[108 kB\]
Fetched 108 kB in 1s (110 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Without having looked into this in detail, it would appear whatever repo you are using doesn't have 3.10.8 available, but instead offers 3.10.6 as the latest release. You could consider building from source, which is available here https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3108/, but I would expect that to be far more trouble than it's worth. Why do you specifically need this version? Is your school requiring you use this specific version on Ubuntu? Is there any reason not to use 3.11, which would support whatever got added in 3.10.8 that you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: `sudo apt update`

Step 2: `sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget`

Step 3: `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.8/Python-3.10.8.tgz`

Step 4: `tar -xf Python-3.10.8.tgz`

Step 5: `cd Python-3.10.8`

Step 6: `./configure --enable-optimizations`

Step 7: `make -j $(nproc)`

Step 9: `sudo make altinstall`

Verify if python 3.10.8 was installed: `python3.10 --version`

Answer (score 1):

WSL runs Ubuntu which in turn packages Python. This means that it allows you to install Python versions that Ubuntu packages. They will not package every minor release. `sudo apt-get install python3.10` installs the latest version packaged by Ubuntu in WSL.

More general, I doubt you need such a specific version for school. The features are the same for all python3.10 versions. Unless you are testing for specific issues within Python there is no need for such a specific package.